# NetCore InputTagHelper using reflection

Tags: asp.net-core, reflection, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a model with lots of properties. Creating or updating theirs views is a troublesome work.

So i trying to use Reflection to create view during runtime: 
(PS: yes, i know the front-end is very import, i should use Vue or other frame to create views at designtime. But I just want to try buildering forms at runtime, yes i am a freak. LOL)

There is my code:

```cs
@{
    var dic = Model.GetAttributePropsByCategory();// get PropertyInfo by CategoryAttribute and custom DisplayIndexAttribute
}
@foreach (var items in dic)
{
    var category = items.Key; //  InfoCategoryAttribute
    foreach (var tuple in items.Value)
    {
        var displayIndex = tuple.Item1; // Custom: DisplayIndexAttribute
        var prop = tuple.Item2; // PropertyInfo

        <input asp-for="@prop.Name" class="form-control"/>
    }
}
```

My target is:

```html
<input class="form-control valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The VIN field is required." id="VIN" name="VIN" value="VIN001" aria-describedby="VIN-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

But the result like this:

```html
<input class="form-control valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="prop_Name" name="prop.Name" aria-describedby="prop_Name-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

So, I read the source code in the [aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers). I found the key is InputTagHelper.For:

```cs
public class InputTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    ...

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

But I can't understand how the InputTagHelper.For was created. Therefor, i dont know how to override it to achieve my target.

Is there any Suggestions? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In source code of [InputTagHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/90e89e970877a39cb048bb6f0e59551351f661c3/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L406), we can find following code snippet will help generate textbox input and the third parameter `For.Name` would be used to set value(s) of textbox `id` and `name` attribute.

```
return Generator.GenerateTextBox(
    ViewContext,
    modelExplorer,
    For.Name,
    modelExplorer.Model,
    format,
    htmlAttributes);
```

And if we debug the source code, we will find the value of `For` look like below.

[image]

To achieve your expected result, you can customize it and pass `For.Model.ToString()` to `GenerateTextBox` method rather than `For.Name`, like below.

```
return Generator.GenerateTextBox(
    ViewContext,
    modelExplorer,
    //For.Name,
    For.Model.ToString(),
    modelExplorer.Model,
    format,
    htmlAttributes);
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Above code just for quick reproducing issue and generating textbox input, if you'd like to achieve similar issue for generating other types of html input tag, such as checkbox, hidden etc, you may need to check the details of InputTagHelper, source code.